# How to reduce the size of the initrd when compiling your kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

When I compile my own kernel, basically what I do is the following:

1. I download the sources from www.kernel.org and uncompress it.
2. I copy my previous `.config` to the sources and do a `make menuconfig` to watch for the new options and modify the configuration according to the new policy of the kernel.
3. Then, I compile it: `make -j 4`
4. Finally, I install it: `su -c 'make modules_install && make install'`.
5. After a few tests, I remove the old kernel (from `/boot` and `/lib/modules`) and run fully with the new one (this last step saved my life several times! It's a **pro-tip**!).

The problem is that I always get a `/boot/initrd.img-4.x.x` which is huge compared to the ones from my distribution. Here the content of my current `/boot/` directory as an example:

```
# ls -alFh
total 243M
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 16 21:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4.0K Feb 25 09:28 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2.9M Mar  9 07:39 System.map-4.4.0-1-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.1M Mar 11 22:30 System.map-4.4.5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.2M Mar 16 21:26 System.map-4.5.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 170K Mar  9 07:39 config-4.4.0-1-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 124K Mar 11 22:30 config-4.4.5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 126K Mar 16 21:26 config-4.5.0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  512 Jan  1  1970 efi/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Mar 16 21:27 grub/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  19M Mar 10 22:01 initrd.img-4.4.0-1-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 101M Mar 12 13:59 initrd.img-4.4.5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 103M Mar 16 21:26 initrd.img-4.5.0
drwx------  2 root root  16K Apr  8  2014 lost+found/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3.5M Mar  9 07:30 vmlinuz-4.4.0-1-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4.1M Mar 11 22:30 vmlinuz-4.4.5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4.1M Mar 16 21:26 vmlinuz-4.5.0
```

As you may have noticed, the size of my `initrd.img` files are about 10 times bigger than the ones from my distribution.

So, do I do something wrong when compiling my kernel? And, how can I reduce the size of my `initrd.img`?

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Extracting_the_cpio_archive and see what's making it so huge. It could be either tons of kernel modules or libraries... or something else entirely. If you don't look at the contents of the archive it's just guesswork.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is because all the kernel modules are not stripped. You need to strip it to down its size.

Use this command:

```
SHW@SHW:/tmp# cd /lib/modules/<new_kernel>
SHW@SHW:/tmp# find . -name *.ko -exec strip --strip-unneeded {} +
```

This will drastically reduce the size.
After executing above command, you can proceed to create initramfs/initrd

`man strip`

> ```
>    --strip-unneeded
>        Remove all symbols that are not needed for relocation processing.
> ```

Comment: Wow, I would never have though that stripping the modules would divide the size of the `initrd` image by 10... Thanks a lot, it worked fine!

Comment: The should be a space between `{}` and `+`.

Comment: Is there a way to do the stripping at compile time *before* automatic kernel signing?

Answer (score 31):

I did some extra research on the problem to know what is the best way to get the modules stripped and here is the full process I found (still SHW did bring the answer but the process I found is somehow more standardized):

1. Download the sources from `www.kernel.org` and uncompress it.
2. Copy your previous `.config` to the sources and do a `make menuconfig` to watch for the new options and modify the configuration according to the new policy of the kernel.
3. Then, compile it:

   ```
   $> make -j 4
   ```
4. Finally, install it:

   ```
   $> su -c 'make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install && make install'
   ```
5. After a few tests, remove the old kernel from `/boot` and `/lib/modules` directories.

The `INSTALL_MOD_STRIP` when set to `1` add a `strip --strip-debug` when installing the module, which is enough to reduce the size drastically.

See: [INSTALL_MOD_STRIP](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt#148) in `Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt`.

Answer (score 18):

You could also change the configuration of your `initramfs.conf`

Find the file at `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`

There is a setting that says `MODULES=most` this includes most of the modules kn your initrd image.

Change it to `MODULES=dep` this makes the initramfs generator guess which modules to include.

Check out the manpage for initramfs.conf [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man5/initramfs.conf.5.html).

NOTE 1: After performing the above steps the size of my initramfs image reduced from 282 MB to 99 MB.( this is still large enough but its a significant improvement)

NOTE 2: I also tried stripping the kernel modules at `/lib/modules/<kernel version>`. The modules supplied by the OS updates are stripped (size  = 211 MB) and thus the corresponding intiramfs image is around 15 MB. After stripping the modules of the vanilla kernel that I compiled myself the size of the folder was 185 MB and the intramfs image was 16 MB. So after all optimizations the size came down from 282 MB to 16 MB!! For stripping use this code

```
find /lib/modules/<kernel_release>/ -iname "*.ko" -exec strip --strip-unneeded {} \;
```

In the above code replace `<kernel_release>` with the kernel version that you wish to strip the modules from.

For more discussion view this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895816/how-do-i-strip-local-symbols-from-linux-kernel-module-without-breaking-it).

The above code must be run as `sudo` or `su`

Comment: `MODULES=dep`
is a good idea.  and i found  `COMPRESS=xz` helps save more 50% file size compared to lz4.

Comment: dell precision, 5.11.0-43: `most`+`lz4`=150mb and hang at loading initramfs; switching to `dep` lowered ramdisk size to 95mb (still too large to load); switching to `dep`+`xy` compression lowers size to a workable 63mb.